# Wrap my markup for width and centering

Tags: css, html

Here's a sample of what's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/EJuzv/29/

I need to wrap everything within a div so that I may give a width, and center with `margin:0 auto;`. As it is, works in every browser except IE6. Everything I try results in losing my sweet divs that extend 100% to the stick footer.

Can anyone crack this case?

Answer (score 0):

You may very well have tried this approach already, but maybe it'll help you crack this problem. Absolute-positioning the header against the top-left corner is unnecessary and just forces you to pad the "container" holding your three colored elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/piersadrian/mKQ89/1/